# TextField Empty Checking

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to add value of textfield. I want to check textfield is empty or not or checking other value than int. I am newer in Swift. Please help any help would be apperciated.

```
@IBOutlet var label :UILabel!
@IBOutlet var first : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var third : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var second : UITextField!

var bloa :NSString?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func playPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    var a: Int = 0
    var b: Int = 0
    var c: Int = 0
    var d: Int = 0


 if first.text!.isEmpty || second.text!.isEmpty || third.text!.isEmpty {
    return
 }
    else
    {

// If on first textfield there is another value than int they show 
//fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 

    a = (Int)(first.text!)!
    b = Int(second.text!)!
    c = Int(third.text!)!

    d = a + b + c

   label?.text = String (format: "%d",d)
    }
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, what problem are you seeing?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Why are your outlets optionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check if it is empty or not this way:

```
guard let a = Int((first?.text)!), b = Int((second?.text)!) , c = Int((third?.text)!) else {
    print("Not convertable to Int or field are empty")
    return
}
```

And your final code will be:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label :UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var first : UITextField?
    @IBOutlet var third : UITextField?
    @IBOutlet var second : UITextField?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        playBackgroundMusic("Naughty_Boy.mp3")
    }

    @IBAction func playPressed(sender: UIButton) {


        guard let a = Int((first?.text)!), b = Int((second?.text)!) , c = Int((third?.text)!) else {
            print("Not convertable to Int or field are empty")
            return
        }

        let d = a + b + c
        label?.text = String (format: "%d",d)
    }
}
```

Comment: If i am enter other than integer value in textfield   a = (Int)(first.text!)! show fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Nopes Dear i Have not used UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad

Comment: you don't want `UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad`?

Comment: Nopes .. I have to used Default KeyBoard

Comment: If you took the code from my answer then why is my answer not the accepted one? lol

Comment: Because he is getting error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` which I solved.. :) @Swinny89

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if first!.text == "" || second!.text == "" || third!.text == "" {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the keyboard for all these text boxes as below screenshot and change is marked in red rectangle. You don't need to check the given character/word is integer or not in the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set your keyboard type to Number Pad from the Storyboard. then do this in code:

```
@IBAction func playPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if first?.text?.isEmpty || second?.text?.isEmpty || third?.text?.isEmpty {

    }
}
```